# How to compare errno in Go?

Tags: c, go, cgo

In Cgo, you can't get the value of errno directly, but you can get the result of it after a function call using a double return value. e.g. `ret, err := C.write(...)`. However, it seems like this `err` is just an opaque error interface and can't be compared with errno constants. How can I do, e.g. something like this:

```
ret, err := C.my_func()
if ret == -1 {
    // error signaled
    if err == C.EAGAIN {
        // do it again
    } else {
        return err
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

This code does not compile since `invalid operation: err == _Ciconst_EAGAIN (mismatched types error and int)`. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error type will be [`syscall.Errno`](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall/#Errno), which you can assert and compare.

```
ret, err := C.my_func()
if errno, ok := err.(syscall.Errno); ret == -1 && ok {
    // error signaled
    if errno == C.EAGAIN {
        // do it again
    } else {
        return err
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer. However, for anyone reading, you should always check the returned value for -1 (or whatever is documented to signal the error) rather than checking errno for nil, since there is no guarantee that errno is zero on success. See https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/programming/GoCgoErrorReturns

Comment: @cry0genic: good point, I'll add a check in the example too, though like you said, you need to check for the correct condition based on the return signal.