# Cannot convert nil (untyped nil value) to bool with cgo

Tags: go, cgo

I have the following error message occur:

```golang
cannot convert nil (untyped nil value) to boolcompiler
```

the error stems from the following code:

```golang
package system

import "C"
import log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"

func ResetInterruptSignalHandler() {
    _, err := C.resetInterruptSignalHandler()
    if err != nil {
        log.Warnf("Failed to reset interrupt signal handle/golang.org/x/tools/internal/typesinternalr: %v.", err, nil)
    }
}
```

The error occurs within my error block:

```
if err != nil
```

How can I convert `nil` to a typed `bool` and is that even my best option?

Comment: It looks like the type of `err` is `bool`.  If so, use `if err {...` or `if !err {` depending on whether true is success or failure.

Comment: An untyped `nil` equates to the default value (or nil value) of any given type. For `bool`, the nil value is `false`, so if `if err {` doesn't work (just using `err` as a bool), you can just use a type assertion (`ok := err.(bool)`), and use `ok` from there on. With type assertions, it's up to you to make sure the type assertion worked: `bErr, ok := err.(bool)` -> `bErr` will be the bool value of the assertion, `ok` will be true if the type assertion was successful, `false` if not. When dealing with CGO errors, it's possible the error value is an `int32` value, so keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

There are several oddities in the code you've quoted.  For instance:

> ```
> log.Warnf("Failed to reset interrupt signal handle/golang.org/x/tools/internal/typesinternalr: %v.", err, nil)
> ```

If you snip out the `/golang.org/x/tools/internal/typesinternal` you get text that matches the file linked below.

Most of the code appears to be a cut-and-paste of [this file from github.com/gravitational/teleport](https://github.com/gravitational/teleport/blob/v4.3.10/lib/system/signal.go), but the comment that goes above `import "C"` is missing.  Without the comment above the `import "C"` line, the code should fail to compile, but not with the error you've shown.

When using cgo and calling a function like the one in the comment at the top of the linked file (which is missing from the odd-ified version you posted), the two return values are:

- the return value from the C function, and
- a `syscall.Errno`-wrapped `errno`, if the C `errno` was nonzero, or nil

So `err` should be comparable to `nil`, and is when I write a reasonably comprehensive test.

Note that it's a bit sloppy to test *only* `err` here, because—as [cry9genic noted in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64067102/how-to-compare-errno-in-go#comment113293076_64067281) on [How to compare errno in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64067102/1256452)—C (or C++) code may spuriously set `errno` nonzero even on success.  In this particular case, where we're just going to call `sigaction` and then maybe `signal`, that shouldn't happen.  But for belt-and-suspenders (or belt-and-braces) programming we should check the returned value for nonzero *before* inspecting the returned error.

Here's a more general test case showing the various issues, consisting of three files: `main.go`, `somefunc.c`, and `somefunc.h` (in that order):

```golang
package main

/*
#include "somefunc.h"
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
)

func show(i int) {
    ret, err := C.somefunc(C.int(i))
    var errno int
    if err != nil {
        errno = int(err.(syscall.Errno))
    }
    fmt.Printf("for %d: ret = %v, err = %T(%v) (%d)\n", i, ret, err, err, errno)
}

func main() {
    show(1)
    show(0)
    show(3)
}
```

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "somefunc.h"

/*
 * The somefunc() function is a silly function that always succeeds
 * when passed zero, fails with EOPNOTSUPP when passed 1, and mostly
 * fails with EBADF (though this assumes fd 19 is not open).
 */
int somefunc(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        /* avoid setting errno */
        return 0;
    }
    /*
     * fd 19 should be closed, so always set errno to EBADF,
     * then override it for input value zero.
     */
    if (i == 1 || isatty(19)) {
        errno = EOPNOTSUPP;
        return 42;
    }
    return i;
}
```

```c
int somefunc(int);
```

Building and running this:

```
$ go build
$ GOMAXPROCS=1 ./cgo_ex4    
for 1: ret = 42, err = syscall.Errno(operation not supported) (45)
for 0: ret = 0, err = <nil>(<nil>) (0)
for 3: ret = 3, err = syscall.Errno(bad file descriptor) (9)
```

shows that, indeed, even if this code didn't *purposely* set errno, it could *accidentally* (well, accidentally-on-purpose) set it for the `return 3` case.  (Only a return value of 42 means "we also set errno explicitly.")

Note that by calling it with `1` first, we (attempt to) show that Cgo zeros out errno at start.  To make this really work we have to run with `GOMAXPROCS=1`, or add a `runtime.LockOSThread` call, in case errno is a thread-local variable in the C code; I did the former.